# Custom validation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I would like to have a custom annotation to verify if the email in a form is unique or not.  Aldready created successfully a "ValidEmail" annotation.

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = EmailValidatorImpl.class)
public @interface ValidEmail {
    String message() default "{error.validEmail}";
    String[] groups() default {};
}
```

Implementation class :

```
public class EmailValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<ValidEmail, String> {

private static String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
private Pattern pattern;
private Matcher matcher;

@Override
public void initialize(ValidEmail annotation) {
    pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return isValidEmail(email);

}

private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    CharSequence emailstr = email;
    matcher = pattern.matcher(emailstr);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

}

I would like now to build a "uniqueEmail" annotation.

```
public class UniqueEmailValidatorImpl implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

private UserServices userServices;

@Override
public void initialize(UniqueEmail annotation) {
    this.userServices = annotation.getUserServices();
}

@Override
public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return isUniqueEmail(email);

}

private boolean isUniqueEmail(String email) {
    try {
        userServices.findByEmail(email);
    } catch (UserDoesNotExistException e) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

}

Since I'm following IoC (with Spring), I really don't like creating an instance of the user service layer directly in the initialize method.  How would you suggest to solve this?  Could the annotation have the reference to the instance?

```
@Override
public void initialize(UniqueEmail annotation) {
    this.userServices = annotation.getUserServices();
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thx!

Comment: Hmm, there is already a pretty good API for validating emails (javamail), why don't you use it?

Comment: You are right but I need to validate against my database if the email exists.  The "ValidEmail" was only to try this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would not recommend to use your Services in your validators (with respect to MVC and being side effect free). As you use Spring why not injecting your service?

```
@Autowired
public void setUserService(final UserServices userServices) {
    this.userServices = userServices
}
```

Comment: Hi, first thk for the answer.  If you don't recommend, what would be your approach on this?

Comment: A Validator should in my opinion be as small as possible to be reusable. I personally would throw an exception in my Business Logic Layer (i.e. Service Layer) and handle it accordingly. I am sure there are a lot of ppl who would not agree. That said @Autowired will solve your problem  if you need/want access your DB from your validators.

Answer (score 1):

You should just inject your `userServices` dependency.  Depending on how you've got your project structured, this is either autowired, constructor-injected, or setter-injected.

It's **far** more restrictive to do it in the other manner, as annotations require that everything set inside of them be a compile-time constant, so you could only really have `String` and `Class` objects in there anyway, and you'd have to go instantiate the object you cared about via reflection.  Makes more sense to use Spring to do this.

Further, your actual validation approach is suspect.  I would expect that `findByEmail` should return whether or not the user by email exists in the database; that is, a `boolean`.  Using `try...catch` in this manner seems inappropriate, and is very inefficient, as your validator will likely be called *very* frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just inject `UserServices`?

```
@Autowired
private UserServices userServices;
```